# Laravel 5 - How can we access image from storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to view profile pic when page loads. I have used laravel storage for upload image but I don't know how to retrieve and view image. Please check my below code and help me.

Current image folder is storage/app/1/1.jpeg

**Laravel Code**

```
public function index()
{
        $id = Input::get('id');
        User::findOrFail($id);
        $file = Storage::get($id.'/'.$id.'.'.'jpeg'); 
        return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
}
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.post("/viewProfile/image", { id: 1 })
                .done(function( data ) {
                    $('#responseImage').html('<img src="'+data+'">');
        });
    })
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="responseImage"> </div>
```

**Firebug Console Response**

```
Please find the attached file
```

[image]

**Firebug Console header**
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly linking the picture? You coded Storage::get($id.'/'.$id.'.'.'jpeg'); but you told us you are looking for /storage/app/. Shouldn't it be rather Storage::get('app/'.$id.'/'.$id.'.'.'jpeg'); ?

Comment: @CDF, Thanks for your reply. The path is correct. In Laravel 5 storage method default path is storage/app/. We can edit this (config/filesystems.php).

Comment: Ok thanks. I see you edited your post with the picture. Can you also post the headers your browser returns?

Comment: @CDF, I updated my post.

Comment: you want to store the image in folder?

Comment: @User, No, I need to view image from folder

Comment: ok. Your images are storing in .jpg format in folder??

Comment: ok k.are u getting any error messages??

Comment: @User, No error message

Comment: what details are storing in database for images like image name are image paths or total image with BLOB type???

Comment: @User, I am not storing any data in database

Comment: are you getting id from database right?? that is whose id and,and what is ur perpose for displaying image

Comment: @User, Currently id is passing manually "$.post("/viewProfile/image", { id: 1 })". Not getting any id from database.

Comment: ok just you want images from folder right???

Comment: `data` in your `<img src=` is the whole content of the image. you need to follow the data uri schema to make it right. check out here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to put the image content inside your `img` tag. You can simply point your `src` attribute to `viewProfile/image/:id` which will display the image.

Edit:

Your index function is retrieving the image from storage and displaying it, so that if you visit `viewProfile/image/1`, you will see the image in your browser.

And then your Javascript function is sending a request to that page, and the output retrieved is added to the `src` attribute in your `img` tag. But the src attribute only accepts the path to the actual image, not the image data itself unless you use `data`.

So to fix your problem, keep your index function as it is, and to display the user image in the view, do the following instead of your `div`:

```
<img src="/viewProfile/image/1">
```

In this case, your image should be displayed and you don't need to use your Javascript function. You can change your controller to pass the an `$id` variable and change `1` to `{{ $id }}`

Comment: I didn't get. Would you please write any sample code.

Comment: I will update my answer in second, just wanted to explain and make sure I understand what you're trying to do.